pip install libyang failed on wsl2 ubuntu 22.04.3 and python 3.9.19
same error for the following install command on ubuntu 22.04.3 on WSL2 with python 3.9:

pip install libyang==1.7.0
pip install libyang

      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/root/workspace/yang/.venv3/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/_libyang.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/_libyang.o -Werror -std=c99
      build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/_libyang.c:574:10: fatal error: libyang/libyang.h: No such file or directory
        574 | #include <libyang/libyang.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

What's missing in my environment?
